# Is it possible to INSERT into a table via an IF EXISTS... ELSE?

Tags: sql-server

I am attempting to use a stored procedure to INSERT into a table, based on the values entered. However, in that INSERT statement, I would like to use an IF NOT EXISTS (execute another stored procedure) ELSE insert using this select statement. However, I am getting the incorrect syntax message whenever I type it out. Does anyone know if this is possible? Below is what the entire stored procedure looks like.

```
USE [CARDS]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[usp_insert_all_data]    Script Date: 7/11/2021 3:25:51 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

-- =============================================
-- Author:      ???
-- Create date: 07/011/2021
-- Description: This stored procedure is meant to provide a one-stop to insert player information
-- =============================================
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_insert_player_detail]
    --PLAYER INFO
    @player_id INT = NULL
    ,@player_first_name NVARCHAR(55) = NULL
    ,@player_last_name NVARCHAR(55) = NULL
    ,
    --PLAYER DETAILS INFO
    @pd_player_id INT = NULL
    ,@pd_team_id INT = NULL
    ,@pd_position_id INT = NULL
    ,@pd_sport_id INT = NULL
    ,@pd_throw_hand CHAR(1) = NULL
    ,@pd_bat_hand CHAR(1) = NULL

    --TEAM INFO (IF NECESSARY)
    ,@team_name VARCHAR(55) = NULL
    ,@team_location VARCHAR(55) = NULL
    ,@team_sport_id VARCHAR(55) = NULL

    --SPORT INFO (IF NECESSARY)
    ,@sport_name VARCHAR(55) = NULL
    
    --POSITION INFO (IF NECESSARY)
    ,@position_name VARCHAR(55) = NULL

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[t_player_detail] (
        [player_id]
        ,[team_id]
        ,[position_id]
        ,[sport_id]
        ,[throw_hand]
        ,[bat_hand]
        ,[shot_hand]
        )
    VALUES (
        --Set the PLAYER NAME here.
        (
            BEGIN
            IF NOT EXISTS (
                    SELECT ply.player_id
                    FROM t_player ply WITH (NOLOCK)
                    JOIN t_player_detail pld ON ply.player_id = pld.player_id
                    WHERE first_name = @player_first_name
                        AND last_name = @player_last_name
                    )
                EXEC usp_insert_new_player
            ELSE
                SELECT ply.player_id
                FROM t_player ply WITH (NOLOCK)
                JOIN t_player_detail pld ON ply.player_id = pld.player_id
                WHERE first_name = @player_first_name
                    AND last_name = @player_last_name
        END
            )
        --Set the TEAM NAME here.
        ,(
            SELECT team_id
            FROM t_team WITH (NOLOCK)
            WHERE team_name = @team_name
                AND team_location = @team_location
            )
        --Set the POSITION here.
        ,(
            SELECT position_id
            FROM t_position WITH (NOLOCK)
            WHERE position_name = @position_name
                AND sport_id IN (
                    SELECT sport_id
                    FROM t_sport WITH (NOLOCK)
                    WHERE sport_name = @sport_name
                    )
            )
        --Set the SPORT here.
        ,(
            SELECT sport_id
            FROM t_sport
            WHERE sport_name = @sport_name
            )
        --Set THROW HAND here.
        ,'R'
        --Set the BAT HAND here.
        ,'L'
        --Set the SHOT HAND here.
        ,NULL
        )
END
GO
```

Comment: Why is it necessary to put all of the logic in one INSERT statement? Can't you do the IF/ELSE logic, store the result in a variable, and then INSERT?

Comment: You cannot use flow control statements in SQL DML statements.

Comment: Side note: ["Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere"](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: @NealBurns That makes WAY more sense. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @stickybit thanks for that info. I am learning how to write stored procedures right now.

Comment: @Larnu thank you for your comment. I am very clear on its usage. It's a force of habit as I write loads more selects than updates in my day-to-day, and I always start my UPDATE with a SELECT, then modify it to an UPDATE. I just had not gone through and cleared them out yet. Also, its a personal database I'm making for myself, so dirty reads are not a concern, as I am the only one running any scripts. However, I appreciate your comment, despite its lack of relevance to the question that was asked.

Comment: If you want your entire proc to use NOLOCK then you can just put `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;` at the top.... but I agree with comments that it's an often misused keyword, although you would appear to understand it better than most!